# StrongLoop Validation Error and required fields

Tags: mysql, json, api, loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm working with StrongLoop and Loopback to create an API. I have extended the built-in `User` model to my own model called `people`. I don't want the `User` model to require an email like it does by default, so I followed [this work around](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/1137), and now when I create users with the default `User` model, email isn't required. But when I'm using my `people` model, it is still required. What am I missing here?

Also, when I get a strange error when I connect my `people` model to my MySQL database. When I can create users just fine with it if I have the default memory connector on i.e. using `db` datasource, but when I connect it to MySQL database I get:

```
{
  "error": {
    "name": "ValidationError",
    "status": 422,
    "message": "The `people` instance is not valid. Details: `username` is     invalid (value: \"username123\"); `email` is invalid (value: \"testing@email.com\").",
"statusCode": 422,
"details": {
  "context": "people",
  "codes": {
    "username": [
      "uniqueness.Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'realm' in 'field list'"
    ],
    "email": [
      "uniqueness.Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'realm' in 'field list'"
    ]
  },
  "messages": {
    "username": [
      "is invalid"
    ],
    "email": [
      "is invalid"
    ]
  }
},
"stack": "ValidationError: The `people` instance is not valid. Details: `username` is invalid (value: \"username123\"); `email` is invalid (value: \"testing@email.com\").\n    at /var/www/photo-app/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/dao.js:265:12\n    at ModelConstructor.<anonymous> (/var/www/photo-app/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/validations.js:487:13)\n    at ModelConstructor.next (/var/www/photo-app/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/hooks.js:75:12)\n    at done (/var/www/photo-app/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/validations.js:484:25)\n    at /var/www/photo-app/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/validations.js:558:7\n    at ModelConstructor.<anonymous> (/var/www/photo-app/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/validations.js:357:5)\n    at allCb (/var/www/photo-app/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/dao.js:1483:7)\n    at /var/www/photo-app/node_modules/loopback-connector-mysql/node_modules/loopback-connector/lib/sql.js:1061:14\n    at cbForWork (/var/www/photo-app/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/observer.js:150:34)\n    at /var/www/photo-app/node_modules/loopback-connector-mysql/node_modules/loopback-connector/lib/sql.js:413:7"
  }
}
```

And here is what that model looks like:

```
"name": "people",
  "base": "User",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": true
    },
    "username": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
   },
    "email": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "password": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "created": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured this out. First, the email was still being required because the work around is specifying the `User` model to not require the email and only the `User` model. I thought because I inherited from the `User` model it would not require an email. You need to specifically assign that work around to your new model. In my case, `people`. Like so:

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  delete app.models.people.validations.email;
};
```

As for the validation errors, this was because I'm using MySQL and I didn't have all the fields of the `User` model in my database. I'm told this isn't an issue with MongoDB or other NoSQL types. But if it's relational you have to include all fields of the base model as well, even if you don't use them. using the `autoMigrate()` or `autoUpdate()` will prevent this from happening as well.

Comment: Hi, i am still facing this issue can you let me know the detail answer